# Лучший способ очень часто отправлять запросы от клиента к серверу на java

Tags: javascript, java, rest

Я хочу написать симуляцию вируса ([например](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UdlEHjm-gU&ab_channel=DomDavid)) с сервером на java и клиентом на js.

В двух словах о симуляции: у нее есть метод `makeOneStep()`, который меняет состояние симуляции (координаты объектов в ней и то, как объекты отображаются). Клиент должен очень часто отправлять запросы к серверу, чтобы анимировать симуляцию. Как лучше всего отправлять настолько частые запросы?

Была идея отправлять информацию пачками (скажем, по 4000 шагов симуляции в запросе), но не уверен, что это лучший вариант.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Люди избегают DoS атаки, а вы его хотите создать :)

Comment: "но не уверен, что это лучший вариант" - прекрасный вариант, если в одном шаге не большие данные

Comment: Не знаю какая там анимация, т.к. вы не предоставили сам код. Если есть возможность из полученных небольших данных от сервера, высчитывать саму анимацию на клиенте, то делайте это на клиенте. Если же такой возможности нет, то лучше наверное пачками, но вам следует учитывать, что пользователь может отправлять сразу по несколько запросов в секунду, тем самым организовать DoS атаку.